# USB 3.0 hub ability to handle data transfer AND power (for external hard drives)

Tags: hard-drive, usb

Many (if not most—on Amazon) current USB 3.0 external hard drives are not externally powered. They depend on their USB connection to both power and data transfer.

The 3.0 USB hub I just ordered says in its manual (not on Amazon) “Charging ports do NOT support data transfer and USB 3.0 ports do NOT support charging” This seems to indicate that it will not handle these external hard drives.

Which USB hubs will and how many external drives will they handle?

Comment: I'm just guessing that charging refers to charging a battery, not powering a USB device.  That hub may have a special high current charging port.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to choose any USB 3.0 hub with external power supply (AC/DC adapter).

For example, the [TP-LINK UH720](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-4761_UH720.html) or [D-Link DUB-1340](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/home-solutions/connect/usb/dub-1340-4-port-superspeed-usb-3-hub).